# Replace for iframe to render complete html document

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, iframe

Is there a way to render a complete html document which also has script and style headers, inside an html tag (not iframe). I am getting this html document as response from an AJAX post request.

Comment: So what is specific problem?

Comment: I don't want to use an iframe on my website.

Comment: Fine...that is already stated. You said you get page by ajax so what happens when you insert it? You have provided next to no information about either page

Comment: So, currently I am using an iframe to display the page. But the iframe seems to be causing memory leaks only in the chrome browser. It works perfectly fine on firefox and IE. I want to know if there are any alternates for iframe tag.

Comment: Wouldn't be the iframe itself causing that, would be whatever is running in the iframe

Comment: But why would this happen only on chrome?

Comment: Far too many unknowns for anyone to answer that, in fact we know **nothing** about the page

Comment: True, I haven't given much context on that. But can you suggest any alternate to iframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<template>` element, [`element.attachShadowRoot()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow). See [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM). Note [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot#Browser_compatibility)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <template>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        :host {
          color: blue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      abc
      <script>
        console.log("shadowDOM")
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
  </template>
  <script>
    var shadow = document.body.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
    var template = document.querySelector("template");
    var shadowContent = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    shadow.appendChild(shadowContent);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: should note limited browser support though

Comment: @charlietfl Included browser compatibility note at updated post.